# Laravel Eloquent: count and ratio in the same db request

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Dear expert I would like to have your help on the following

I want to send the name, count, and ratio (count of this status over the total number of posts by the same category) per category in the dashboard in the same query.

With the following I can return the name, count but i have no idea how I can calculate the ratio too. I would appreciate your help

```
//Top claim solved by category

    $solvedByCategoryCollection = Post::join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'posts.category_id')
    ->groupBy('categories.id')
    ->where('posts.status_id', '3')
    ->get(['categories.id', 'categories.name', DB::raw('count(categories.id) as count')]);
```

Comment: Please provide some more data on your db request and schema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do the job?

```
//Top claim solved by category

$solvedByCategoryCollection = Post::join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'posts.category_id')
->groupBy('categories.id')
->where('posts.status_id', '3')
->get([
    'categories.id',
    'categories.name',
    DB::raw('count(categories.id) as count'),
    DB::raw(sprintf('(count(*)/(%s) ) as ratio', Post::select(DB::raw('COUNT(*)'))->toSql()))
]);
```

Comment: Just found a little problem, actually the ration should be the TotalSolvedInThisCategory/TotalSubmittedOfThisCategory.

Comment: In that case I don't know a way to do it in a single query but in two instead: one to get the count per solved category and one to get the count submitted. After these two queries you could generate the data you need and crack on with the dashboard related functionality.

Comment: Thank you @Adrian. For sure it is the only way.